# Google Cloud SDK installation Python error

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

While trying to install Google Cloud SDK on Windows 10, I get the following error:

[image]

[image]

> I have Python installed on my computer, and I added the PATH to the `Scripts folder`

[image]

> and also tried to add to an environment variable:

[image]

Comment: It seems that you have the latest version of Python (Python 3.8) installed. I will try to recommend you to install [Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-375/) and then carefully following this section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows) and test.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud SDK CLI does not fully support Python 3 yet.

Unless you are experienced with Google Cloud and Python and the SDK libraries, I recommend first removing Python 3 and installing Python 2.7. Then Install the CLI.

You can then add Python 3 after setting up the CLI for your other developments.

For details on the CLI support for Python 3 run the command `gcloud topic startup` once you have the CLI setup with Python 2.

Note: Python 3 GA support was released in version 2.74 (12-17-2019). However, some features still require Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1) Install Python (add it to PATH); and
   2) Install Google Cloud SDK, but uncheck the "Bundled Python" option.